# Trying to add an index to a ttable using substring of field

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to create an index using the first 2 characters of field + a 2nd field. i'm using ttable. I've tried substring(part_no,1,2);location but get error when I open the table.

```
cdsOrders := TClientDataSet.Create(nil); 
with cdsOrders.FieldDefs do begin 
    clear; 
    add('LOCATION',ftString,50); 
    add('PART_NO',ftString,35); 
end; 
try 
    with cdsOrders.IndexDefs.AddIndexDef do begin 
        Name := 'part'; 
        Fields := 'substr(part_no,1,2);Location'; 
    end; 
    cdsOrders.IndexName := 'part'; 
    cdsOrders.AutoReposition := false; 
    try 
        cdsOrders.Open;
```

Seems like it should work.  What am i missing?

TIA

Comment: The function name is SUBSTR() in this situation. So try `substr(part_no,1,3)+location`.

Comment: I'm still getting field "substr(part_no,1,2)" not found

Comment: @user3059002 Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the actual code that you are trying to use to create the index

Comment: What DBMS are you connecting to? TTable uses the BDE, which supports multiple database engines (Paradox, dBase, SQL Server, and Oracle, to name a few). Also, why are you still using the BDE, which has been deprecated for many years now?

Comment: cdsOrders := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  
  with cdsOrders.FieldDefs do
    begin
      clear;
      add('LOCATION',ftString,50);
      add('PART_NO',ftString,35);
    end;
  try

    with cdsOrders.IndexDefs.AddIndexDef do
      begin
        Name := 'part';
        Fields := 'substr(part_no,1,2);Location';
      end;

    cdsOrders.IndexName := 'part';
    cdsOrders.AutoReposition := false;

    try
      cdsOrders.Open;

Comment: The code you show lacks the provider and uses a non existent property AutoReposition. Please edit your post and make it complete. As @RemyLebeau said, show a minimal reproducible example demonstrating the error you get.

Comment: @user3059002 The [`TIndexDef.Fields`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TIndexDef.Fields) documentation makes it pretty clear that only field names can be used, not expressions.

Comment: You could try with a [`TFDMemTable`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDMemTable) instead. It looks like it supports [expressions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDIndex.Expression) in its [indexes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.Indexes).

Comment: Index options has to include ixExpression for the index in question. So for example: `cdsOrders.AddIndex('part','substr(part_no,1,2);Location',[ixExpression],'');`

Comment: Easier to create the tables/indexes in database desktop to find out what is possible/acceptable before trying to do it in code.

Comment: @Brian according to the [`AddIndex()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.AddIndex) documentation, `ixExpression` is not supported, only `ixDescending`, `ixCaseInsensitive`, and `ixUnique` are allowed.

Comment: that works.  Thanks

Comment: @RemyLebeau The ancient BDE based TTable version supporting dBase expression indexes: [Bde.DBTables.TTable.AddIndex](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Bde.DBTables.TTable.AddIndex)

Comment: @Brian `cdsOrders` is a `TClientDataSet`, not a `TTable`.

Comment: The only TTable I have ever seen in Delphi is the old BDE based component so I might have been led astray.